# Error connecting Excel to Dashdb

Tags: ibm-cloud

I wanted to connect excel to my bluemix dashdb .  I found and followed the directions in the IBM knowldegebase at [Article](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connect_connecting_excel.html).  But am getting the connection error message box when attempting to open the BLUExcel.odc file as recommended in the article. The error I see basically states:

> SQL30081N A communication Error has been detected.  Communication protocal is tcp/ip.  API used is sockets....Protocol specific error code 10061.

Investigation of the specific 10061 error did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I couldn't connect Excel to any of my dashdb databases so thought I would have a look at the BLUExcel.odc file that gets generated as part of the process.
In there I found the connectionstring had

> Hostname = localhost

so I changed this to the hostname that you find in the Connect tab of the dashdb instance you want to connect to and it works fine.  Hope this helps someone else..